# Copy multiple charts from multiple Excel files to single Word document

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I'm trying to copy around 350 charts (chart sheets) from multiple Excel files into one Word document.

I managed to open a specific Excel file and copy the charts to the Word document.

```vb
Sub copy_pic_excel()
Dim xlsobj_2 As Object
Dim xlsfile_chart As Object
Dim chart As Object

Set xlsobj_2 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlsobj_2.Application.Visible = False
Set xlsfile_chart = xlsobj_2.Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Kiel\Desktop\chart.xls")

Set chart = xlsfile_chart.Charts("chart1")
chart.Select
chart.ChartArea.Copy
With Selection
   .PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, _
     Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
End With

Set chart = xlsfile_chart.Charts("chart2")
chart.Select
chart.ChartArea.Copy
With Selection
   .PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, _
     Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
End With

Set chart = xlsfile_chart.Charts("chart3")
chart.Select
chart.ChartArea.Copy
With Selection
   .PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, _
     Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
End With

Set chart = xlsfile_chart.Charts("chart4")
chart.Select
chart.ChartArea.Copy
With Selection
   .PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, _
     Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
End With

Set chart = xlsfile_chart.Charts("chart5")
chart.Select
chart.ChartArea.Copy
With Selection
   .PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, _
     Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
End With

Set chart = xlsfile_chart.Charts("chart6")
chart.Select
chart.ChartArea.Copy
With Selection
   .PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, _
     Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
End With

Set chart = xlsfile_chart.Charts("chart7")
chart.Select
chart.ChartArea.Copy
With Selection
   .PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, _
     Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
End With

'clean up
Set xlsfile_chart = Nothing
xlsobj_2.Quit
Set xlsobj_2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

This errors every time but it just about works for a small project.

How do I expand this to source the charts from a whole folder for all charts in all .xls files?

Answer (score 0):

To step through all XLS files in a folder you need to use the DIR command. Below is an example of its use. I have it saving the names to cells but you can simply use the name to pass to a function. You will need to change to pathname to the folder you want however there is a simple shortcut of saving the main sheet with the code in the same folder and use Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path to get the current pathname

```
Sub Directory()
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFolderPath As String
Dim strFileName As String
Dim intRow As Integer
Dim intColumn As Integer

intRow = 1
intColumn = 1

strFolderPath = "h:\*.xls"
strFileName = Dir(strFolderPath)

Do
    Sheets("Main").Cells(intRow, intColumn) = strFileName  'test output to sheet
    Debug.Print strFileName 'test output to debug
    strFileName = Dir
    intRow = intRow + 1
Loop Until strFileName = ""
End Sub
```

You then open each workbook (excluding the one with the code) and step through each chart in the workbook using a "for each chart in charts" loop

```
Dim myChart As Chart

For Each myChart In <Workbookname>.Charts
    Debug.Print myChart.Name 
    //or use the myChart object to pass to your code
Next
```